# Preamable.tex File not found?

Tags: errors

I tried to compile the following TeX to get the PDF File through "TeXStudio" Software, but I got a problem as shown in the image.

The original source of this TeX template is found by the following link:
https://github.com/mcschroeder/thesis

Comment: I searched for the file "preamble.tex" from the original source file. It is not found there ;(.

Comment: I did that (%\input{preamble}), but it did not work ;(

Comment: I've edited out the image here: the info is currently public but likely we should be wary of including it

Answer (score 3):

the file is there under the name `preamble.lhs` In that case you can probably simply rename it but in general I believe the `lhs` files are used by a haskell pre-processor to generate tex files so you need to use the `build.hs` haskell program not use tex directly

Comment: Thank you very much for your tip, Mr. David. I am using "TexStudio" within Ubuntu operating System under TeX environment. Could you please explain more what show I do in my situation.

Comment: texstudio is just the editor you use to edit the files, but you are using latex to typeset the document but the files that you show are not latex they are a program written in the haskell programming language that _generates_ latex, so you need to install haskell and run the build.hs haskell program which will generate all the necessary latex files. I do not have haskell installed (and haven't used it this century) so can't offer any more help than that.

Comment: Beside installing "Haskell" and rename "preamble.lhs". Do you mean by your previous comment that I convert the name of the "preamble.lhs" to "preamble.tex"

Comment: no don't rename (that might work if you are just trying a similar template but will not generate this document, for that you need to run build.hs  which is a haskell program to build the document (I assume) as I say I don't have haskell so I can't confirm. It seems very odd to be running someone's personal thesis build in this way why do you need such a haskell setup? @AliMansour

Comment: I installed haskell through the command => curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh, then I run the file build.sh from the terminal at its path. But unfortunately I still have the same problem shown in the image above.